# Simplification of $2^n + 2^{n-1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

I'm working through a proof right now, and have gotten to the statement:

$F(n+1) ≤ 2^n + 2^{n-1}$

This is correct, but according to my answer key, from this statement we can conclude that:

$F(n+1) ≤ 2 \cdot 2^n$

As the next step, which I don't understand. If I try to simplify this expression by factoring, I go:

$2^n + 2^{n-1}$

$2^n + 2^n2^{-1}$

$2^n + (\frac{1}{2})2^n$

$1.5 \cdot 2^n$

How on earth is the answer $2 \cdot 2^n$? I'm sure there's some small, stupid detail I'm missing but I just can't seem to get my head around it.

Comment: $2^n + 2^{n-1}$ does not equal $2 \times 2^n$ but is less than it. So if we've shown that $F(n + 1) \leq 2^n + 2^{n-1}$ then clearly we also know $F(n + 1) \leq 2 \times 2^n$.

Comment: Think about it : $2*2^{n} > 1.5*2^n$ which means the inequality you proved is "stronger" than what is asked of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can conclude this since :
$$1.5 \cdot 2^n < 2 \cdot 2^n$$

Hence,

$$\color{blue}{F(n+1)} ≤ 2^n + 2^{n-1}=1.5 \cdot 2^n \color{blue}{< 2 \cdot 2^n}$$

Comment: Oh jeez...I've been trying for 20 minutes to figure out how I lost the ability to simplify exponents and it's just an equality trick. Thank you, this has been driving me nuts.

Comment: @MMMMMCK Welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

If we have
$$2^n+2^{n-1}$$
We must factor out $2^{n-1}$ to get
$$2^{n-1}(2+1)$$
$$3*2^{n-1}$$
which is less than
$$2*2^n$$
So, since
$$F(n+1) \le 3*2^{n-1}$$
and
$$3*2^{n-1} \le 2*2^n$$
then
$$F(n+1) \le 2*2^n$$

Answer (score 1):

If $a<b$ and $b<c$, then $a<c$. They basically just replaced $1.5\cdot2^n$ with $2^{n+1}$ and used the substitution in the first sentence.

Answer (score 1):

$2^{n-1} \leq 2^n$, so $2^n + 2^{n-1} \leq 2^n + 2^n = 2 \cdot 2^n$.